# A book recommendation about analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, book-recommendation

I have studied calculus and a bit of linear algebra. And now, I'm finding a book about analysis, which I can self-study. Can anyone recommend me a good analysis book which has many examples, and is compact?

Comment: *Mathematical Analysis* by Apostol is great. Depending on your background with proofs, you may want to jump right to Baby Rudin, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis.* Alternatively, you could read through Rudin and supplement with Apostle or other books where Rudin is a bit terse.

Comment: I recommend you " Introduction to Real Analysis" by Robert G. Bartle & Donald R. Sherbert. I used this book some year ago, it is my favorite. Another book is " Calculus, Volume I: One-Variable Calculus, with an Introduction to Linear Algebra" by  Tom M. Apostol.
**Edit** You can find those books here: http://gen.lib.rus.ec/search.php

Comment: It depends on your experience and ability. Spivak's book is highly recommended. Baby Rudin is a piece of beauty, but I don't think it's ideal for self-study. I am very experienced in analysis, and I just recently started working through Baby Rudin to refresh. Some of the problems trip me up in ways most analysis books don't. I'm enjoying it though because I have background.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good book for self study of a First Course in Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/62212/70305) See also [Good First Course in real analysis book for self study](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/188255/70305) and (Self-study Real analysis Tao or Rudin?)[https://math.stackexchange.com/q/373401/70305]

Comment: I don’t care for Apostol, but that’s largely a matter of taste. Baby Rudin is very efficiently organized, but it is **not** a good book for self-study. I consider Bartle’s [*The Elements of Real Analysis*](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/047105464X/ref=dbs_a_def_rwt_bibl_vppi_i2), 2nd ed., significantly better than Bartle & Sherbert. And depending on your current familiarity with proof-oriented math, all of these may be heavy going.

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely try T.Tao's Real Analysis I then Analysis II. It consists of nice exercises and the terminologies are quite simple, and he also gives Remarks at the end of propositions or Theorems which might be a bit too rigorous for new readers to understand fully and thus clears ambiguities.

There's Baby Rudin too, but i would not recommedd it as the first book though, it can be read later after Tao's book

Comment: +1 Good ol' Terence Tao.

Comment: Indeed Tao's book is a masterpiece. I know another one great book though, but its in Bengali :D